# How to submit form in loop in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE in Firefox and submiting a form. The problem is that the form can be sucesfull or unsuccesfull (random). When it's unsuccesfull it will show and error message (AJAX) and I need to try to submit the form again.

I would like to write a test which will be submiting the form until it will redirect me to success page (text present).

Can someone helps me with this? I didn't play with Selenium this way yet.

Comment: Why does the form randomly fail and show an error message?

Comment: It's testing environment of Datacash. This is returning statuses randomly, I can't change this. I want to place an order, datacash is contacted and it can return true or error id (fraud scoring, funds, blocked card,...)

Comment: You can use the flow control extension http://51elliot.blogspot.com/2008/02/selenium-ide-goto.html I haven't used it a lot myself, but it should enable you to do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an extension that adds full-fledged looping, conditional execution, and callable functions to Selenium IDE: [SelBlocks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/).

Dave Hunt mentioned flowControl, which is a possibility. But besides higher-level functionality, a significant difference is that SelBlocks takes eval expressions (regular javascript), which might make checking AJAX status a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium extension goto_sel_ide. This will enable flow control commands.
Then you can use while command, and with help of this you can run script till you get success message.
Let me know whether it is working for you or not